# JavaScript - How to put all of the objects from several nested arrays into a new array of unique objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

I have an an array of objects called `packages`. Each object has a property called `modules`that is another array of objects. Each object in each `modules` array has a unique ID. I want to put each unique object from all of the `modules` arrays into a single array, using the ID.

```
packages = [
  { id: 1, modules:[{ id: 1, name: 'module1' }, { id: 2, name: 'module2' }]},
  { id: 2, modules:[{ id: 1, name: 'module1' }, { id: 3, name: 'module3' }]},
  { id: 3, modules:[{ id: 2, name: 'module2' }, { id: 4, name: 'module4' }]} 
];
```

I need the result to be:

```
allModules = [
  { id: 1, name: 'module1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'module2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'module3' },
  { id: 4, name: 'module4' }
];
```

I'm using TypeScript, but not ES6.

Comment: cool. so what did you try? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In your `packages` definition, line 4, you have { id: 1, name: 'module4' }.  I think this is supposed to be `id: 4`?  But, if your module IDs are all unique to the module, then instead of storing objects with name & id inside arrays, it would be more straightforward to just use an associative array with the id as the key and the name value.

Comment: @PeretteBarella Thanks I fixed the typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Array methods like `reduce` and `filter` to get your list of unique modules:

```js
var packages = [
  { id: 1, modules:[{ id: 1, name: 'module1' }, { id: 2, name: 'module2' }]},
  { id: 2, modules:[{ id: 1, name: 'module1' }, { id: 3, name: 'module3' }]},
  { id: 3, modules:[{ id: 2, name: 'module2' }, { id: 4, name: 'module4' }]} 
]

var result = packages.reduce(function (a, e) {
  return a.concat(e.modules)
}, []).filter(function (e) {
  return !this[e.id] && (this[e.id] = true)
}, {})

console.log(result)
```